# Correct recognition results of Google Speech API

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition

Is it possible to train Google Speech API with sample data to help the recognition in my application?

What I mean is an approach like the one provided by wit.ai and described [here](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart#using-wit-from-websites) (even though the example applies to nlp processing). Basically, if you can predict the interactions your users will have with your bot, you can train it to better perform. For instance, I know the subset of cities that will be used, eg: it seems I cannot make the bot understand me when I say `Zurich`, it becomes `Syria` or `Siberia` but I already know that is not possible. So if I, let's say, can upload a list of preferred words to be used first and then if no match is found there fallback to standard recognition or some similar approach I think it will be achieve better results.

Any idea if it is possible and how? I know those APIs are in beta stage and subject to change, but I would still like to give it a try.

I can upload some code sample of what I am currently doing, though it is just sending an audio and analyzing the result so far, so not really close to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In [recognition config](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig) you can specify alternatives to return you with maxAlternatives field (up to 30). Once you have 30 alternatives with confidence you'll have `Syria` with confidence `0.5`, `Siberia` with confidence `0.01` and `Zurich` with confidence `0.1`. Usually the proper answer is present, although it might not be on the top. You can select best alternative according to your current status.

Comment: don't dispare, it is a side project and atm I have no time to work on it, but as soon as I am back on this I will let you know if your answer helps me (I noticed the confidence already, but may have overlooked at the multiple options, I had the impression there was only one not so sure)

Answer (score 0):

The current Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API allows the user to specify a list of words and phrases that provide hints to the speech recognition task.

From https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180520025357/https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics)):

> `speechContext` - (optional) contains additional contextual information for processing this audio. A context contains the following sub-field:
>   phrases - contains a list of words and phrases that provide hints to the speech recognition task.

For more details, see: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180520025357/https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#phrase-hints)).